# Placement of adjective

Tags: grammar, adjective

In the sentence

> Du bist einer Maus ähnlich.

Why is ähnlich at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ähnlich* is placed there, because one of its uses is to compare:

> Objekt1 Objekt2(Dat) ähnlich sein ~ Object 1 is similar to object 2.

In this use, *ähnlich* is said to be *nachgestellt* (put after, as some prepostions are). Moreover it is not qualifying, it's compairing the objects.

Comment: I have never heard of a grammatical term "nachgestelltes Wort" ... do you have a link for that?

Comment: @Emanuel well, there exists the term *nachgestellte Präposition*

Comment: That's true... that's interesting because that would make "ähnlich" a preposition. However, prepositions can't stand alone, while "ähnlich" can.

Answer (score 2):

We have to see *ähnlich* as part of the verb. The verb is not *sein* but *ähnlich sein*. This is strongly supported by the fact that it rules its own case. *Sein* alone does not call for Dative at all. Adjectives however do not rule a case. 
In a different universe it might just be written as one word - *ähnlichsein*. It is similar to *Fahrrad fahren* or *zurückgehen*. There is no logical reason why one is written as 2 words and the other as one. Or even better... *zumachen* and *zu sein*

> Ich mache die Tür zu.
>
> Die Tür ist zu.

For all verbs there is a different level of adhesion between defining adverbials. For *ähnlich* it is not very strong and yet just as *Fahrrad* or the prefix *ein*, *ähnlich* is the "rest" of the predicate and thus at the end.

> Du bist einer Maus ähnlich.

Just as with all verbs, I can add qualifiers ...and also particles.

> Die Tür ist nicht/kaum/schon/doch/ja/noch zu.
>
> Du bist einer Maus nicht/kaum/schon ähnlich. (not all of them work here)

And I can make comparisons with regular prefixes... although this is somewhat colloquial

> Ich mache die Tür zuer als du sie je gemacht hast.

Officially, this is wrong but it does not trigger a grammar alert as "den Tür" would do.

Comment: Könnte es sein, dass das Problem darin besteht, dass "sein" im Gegensatz zu "machen" ein Kopula ist. Stell dir mal vor das Linking Verb nimmt das "zu" an. Wenn also "zusein" ein Wort wäre. "Die Tür zuist". Und wie klingt erst die Frage? "Zuist die Tür?" - Dann doch lieber ist "Wie/Was ist die Tür? Sie ist zu".

Comment: @Em1... ja, das kann schon sein, dass das wegen dem Kopula Charakter nicht so leicht/gut funktioniert. Aber Vorsicht. "Ich weiß, dass die Tür zuist." ... ok, das sieht komisch aus. Aber "Zuist die Tür?"... das würde nie passieren. Denn wenn, dann wäre "zu" ein trennbarer Präfix "Ist die Tür zu?"